# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/persistence/Persistence javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

Tags: jsf, jpa

Good afternoon, I'm having error in setting jsf, primefaces and jpa (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax / persistence / Persistence) if you can help me thanks! follows the below error:

```
herejavax.servlet.ServletException: javax/persistence/Persistence
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.GenericDAOImpl.getEntityManager(GenericDAOImpl.java:20)
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.GenericDAOImpl.<init>(GenericDAOImpl.java:15)
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.RequerimentoDAOImpl.<init>(RequerimentoDAOImpl.java:7)
com.observatorioLegislativo.logic.impl.RequerimentoLogicImpl.<init>(RequerimentoLogicImpl.java:11)
com.observatorioLegislativo.bean.RequerimentoBean.<init>(RequerimentoBean.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:90)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:72)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:46)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.GenericDAOImpl.getEntityManager(GenericDAOImpl.java:20)
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.GenericDAOImpl.<init>(GenericDAOImpl.java:15)
com.observatorioLegislativo.dao.RequerimentoDAOImpl.<init>(RequerimentoDAOImpl.java:7)
com.observatorioLegislativo.logic.impl.RequerimentoLogicImpl.<init>(RequerimentoLogicImpl.java:11)
com.observatorioLegislativo.bean.RequerimentoBean.<init>(RequerimentoBean.java:15)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:90)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:72)
org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:46)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

codigo do pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.observatorioLegislativo</groupId>
<artifactId>observatorioLegislativo</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Mojarra (implementação do JSF 2) --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrimeFaces (biblioteca de componentes) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4J -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons Logging (abstrai a implementação de logging) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

 </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that javax.persistence.Persistence class is not found in your classpath, I guess you are not using an application server, I think you're using tomcat, so you must put all the libraries that your application needs in the lib of your server, or you can copy all the jars to the WEB-INF/lib folder of your appplication, so you must copy the jpa library hibernate-entitymanager-xxxx.jar and the others to the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

That same friend, it worked! I put all the dependencies that were in my pom.xml inside tomcat, then it worked! thank you!